How to check if missing values are for the same index in two data columns?
I am trying to break down a series of data cleaning and analysis steps written by others.
The dataset used 'titanic' has the following two columns, 'embarked' and 'embark_town'. I don't understand the below line of code:
#to check if the missing values for embark and embarked column are for the same person,
# otherwise both columns could be filled based on the other column's value
df['embarked'][(df['embarked'].isnull()) & (df['embark_town'].isnull())]

#output
61     NaN
829    NaN
Name: embarked, dtype: object

what does the line of code mean and how can it check for whether missing values are for the same person? What does the output mean?

Each row in the dataset should be one person, so you're already checking that the two values are missing for the same person

Regarding the selection, this is called boolean indexing.

Note that you could also use: df.loc[df[['embarked', 'embark_town']].isnull().all(axis=1), 'embarked']
